# Batch Face Raises Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

Running the code on Mac M1.
When the batch size is equal to 1, after detection 60 images this error raise:

```
Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError
exception: no description
```

The code:

```
if i == (number_of_iterations-1):
        faces = detector.pseudo_batch_detect(images_list[start:number_of_images], cv=False)   
print(f'start = {start}', f'end = {end}')
faces = detector.pseudo_batch_detect(images_list[start:end], cv=False)
```

Comment: Post full error stacktrace and more code so people can see the context in which this code runs